# How to test if array elements are all equal in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a script that checks if the user of the wheel group is on the list of allowed users, if `true` then writes the value `0` in the list `result`, if false then `1`. Then I found a piece of code that checks if all values in the result list are the same. My problem is that when none of the users are on the list they all get `1` and this makes the test pass and it should fail

What do I need? Help with code review to make the test work for cases:

result=(all members are 0) test pass

result=(minimum one member has 1) test fail

result=(all members are 1) test fail

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./colorama.conf

message="verify group wheel members"
wheel_members_list=(
    "username_01"
    "username_02"
    "username_03"
    )
#echo ${wheel_members_list[@]}

output=`getent group wheel | awk -F: '{print $4}' | tr , '\n'`
#echo $output

result=()

for username in $output;do
    if [[ ${wheel_members_list[@]} =~ (^|[[:space:]])$username($|[[:space:]]) ]];then
        result+=(0)
    else
        result+=(1)
    fi
done

echo state: ${result[@]}

if [ "${#result[@]}" -gt 0 ] && [ $(printf "%s\000" "${result[@]}" | 
       LC_ALL=C sort -z -u |
       grep -z -c .) -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo pass
    exit 0
else
  echo fail
  exit 1
fi
```

EDIT: for the moment i solved it with if condition, but i will appreciate help with the first version

```
for state in ${result[@]}; do
    if [ $state -eq 1 ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: It always seems wrong to write anything similar to `$(grep -z -c .) -eq 1`.  But beside that, the logic in your first attempt is flawed. You simply do not care if "all the elements in the list are the same", but whether any of the elements in the list is 1.  In which case you can do `if printf '%s\000' "${result[@]}" | grep -q -z 1; then` or `if [[ ${result[@]} =~ 1 ]]; then` (Note: these omit the size check and reverse the logic, and the `then` branch is your failure case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since result is an array of only 0's and 1's, you can do this most efficiently by using pure bash:

```bash
if [[ "${result[*]}" =~ 1 ]]; then
    echo fail
else
    echo pass
fi
```

This way is less efficient but more in line with what you were trying, you just gotta use the fact that grep fails if it finds no match:

```
if printf "%s\0" "${result[@]}" |  grep -zq 1; then
    echo fail
else
    echo pass
fi
```